# Not able to update state from the component which is used Link Tag in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Not able to update state from the component which is used Link Tag.

Parent Component:

```
<Link to={{
   pathname: "/editForm/" + data.id,
   callFn: {
             updateForm: updateForm,
             data: data
           }
 }}>Edit</Link>
```

In Child component,

```
 const handleSave = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            history.push("/");
            props.location.callFn.updateForm(data.id, formVal);
        }
```

The update state call in Parent Component is,

```
        updateForm(idd, formVal) {
                console.log(formVal); //is displaying the updated data, but not able to update states

    this.setState({employee: this.state.employee.filter(employee => employee.id !== idd)}); //this is not working or triggering.
            }
```

The updated data is coming correctly, but setState is not working inside this function.
Any support on this.

Comment: is the location of updateForm a class?  You should probably upload the full code for that component

Comment: No, that is a function and  part of parent class component.

Comment: yes,  but how do you know employee is not updating after you update the state? You should know setState is asynchronous

Comment: Yes, I am listing the state data in table. I am verifying with that. console.log(this.state.employee) also showing old state data.

Comment: I am getting sometimes : Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.